# Image.FromFile is very very slow

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, infragistics

I am trying to load image icon in infragistics ultrawingrid. For this i am trying to intialize row and based on condition i am loading respective image.

But I have very slow performance when I am trying to use `Image.FromFile()`

Please suggest how to fix for faster loading of grid

```
    Private Sub ugMain_InitializeRow(sender As Object, e As InitializeRowEventArgs) Handles ugMain.InitializeRow
    If e.Row.Cells("Delays").Value = 0 Then
        e.Row.Cells("Indicator").Value = Image.FromFile("Images\\RoundedGreen.png")
    Else
        e.Row.Cells("Indicator").Value = Image.FromFile("Images\\RoundedRed.png")

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: how many different images are there?

Comment: If it's a code which you want to run for each row, then instead of file access for each row, load those images once and put them in a `List<Image>` and use them from that list each time you need.

Comment: Two different images are there. Green Icon and Red Icon. I cannot load all images at once because each row has to satisfy condition based on it i can show green image or red image

Comment: @RezaAghaei How is that

Comment: It is also not likely ImageFromFile that is slow, but redrawing each row after you have modified it will aggravate the issue.  I'd use a Dictionary, but a collection where the images are loaded once is the key

Comment: @Plutonix. I got you. Can you help me with modifying above code how to use it

Comment: You can also use `Resources.resx` for your images instead of relying on filesystem.

Comment: No because I do not know that control.  Another problem may be that `InitializeRow` is not the ideal event to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Image.FromFile` is not slow, but the way you are calling it for each record, **may** cause some performance penalty for you. You are calling that method which interact with filesystem for each row.

Instead of loading those images from file system for each row in your grid, you can use either of these options:

- You can load those images once and put them in a `List<Image>` and then each time you need them, get the image from list by index, `Images[0]` for example. If you want to access those images by key, you can use a `Dictionary<string , Image>` as mentioned by *Plutonix* and then you can get the image using `Images["RoundedGreen"]` for example.
- Instead of relying on images on file system, You can use `Resources.Resx` file of your application to store those images at compile time. Then each time you need to use those images at run-time, you can find them using `My.Resources.RoundedGreen`.

**Example**

For example you can define `Images` member at form level:

```
Dim Images As Dictionary(Of String, Image) = New Dictionary(Of String, Image)()
```

Then somewhere, for example in `Load` event of form, load images:

```
Images.Add("RoundedGreen", Image.FromFile("Path to RoundedGreen image"))
Images.Add("RoundedRed", Image.FromFile("Path to RoundedRed image"))
```

Then wherever you need to use those images, you can get them from `Images` member this way: `Images("RoundedGreen")`

Comment: Performance is better now..But takes like 2 sec to load 14k records with images. Until then grid is blank i can show up some waiting hourly glass